# Integração com DropBox

Tags: novo-recurso

A vezes desejo adicionar uma captura de tela em postagens como muitos aqui, por praticidade escolhi usar o DropBox já que este automaticamente faz o upload para um servidor e cria a URL no *clipbboard* quando a captura é feita.

Porém quando quando tento inserir a imagem preciso visitar o site do DropBox e copiar a URL para então inserir aqui.

Gostaria de sugerir uma melhor integração permitindo assim que apenas informando a URL nativa do DropBox como esta abaixo de exemplo e assim automaticamente a imagem seria inserida da forma adequada ao uso no post, ficando como a imagem a seguir:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd0qurvwxukziac/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-06-20%2011.42.07.png?dl=0
- https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AADJpxr724U3hipc2j8bF4kPdsxRvmvfvElLuYegWTr5Pg/12/40021453/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-06-20%2011.42.07.png/CM3bihMgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygB/W-JffP5IMyRhlZ5pu5Q7kf8VKe391uv5vUOYeE3va0w?size=1024x768&size_mode=2

[image: Captura de Tela da Tentativa de inserção de Imagem via DropBox]

Comment: **Dica**: Tem o [**Lightshot**](http://prnt.sc/) que captura a tela toda ou um lugar especifico quando pressionada a tecla *print screen*. O programa permite fazer o *upload* direto no Imgur ou salvar a imagem no computador. Eu uso ela quando preciso de imagens em uma postagem.

Comment: Tem também o [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) que dá para fazer o mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Posso e espero estar errado quanto a isso, mas o que me parece que acontece é o seguinte:

Isso ocorre porque essas imagens na verdade são páginas HTML contendo uma imagem no meio, e não as próprias imagens.

No caso desta página:

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd0qurvwxukziac/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-06-20%2011.42.07.png?dl=0

O link da imagem para mim é este:

> https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AACUVysOPaCCapLWPuXQgXsN9yP0yuzMRuJ2_9QoBynylQ/12/40021453/png/32x32/1/1434823200/0/2/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-06-20%2011.42.07.png/CM3bihMgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygB/W-JffP5IMyRhlZ5pu5Q7kf8VKe391uv5vUOYeE3va0w?size=1280x960&size_mode=2

Mas para você o link é:

> https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AADJpxr724U3hipc2j8bF4kPdsxRvmvfvElLuYegWTr5Pg/12/40021453/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Captura%20de%20tela%202015-06-20%2011.42.07.png/CM3bihMgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygB/W-JffP5IMyRhlZ5pu5Q7kf8VKe391uv5vUOYeE3va0w?size=1024x768&size_mode=2

Para mim, o seu link dá um erro 403 - Ou seja, tentativa de acesso não autorizada. E o meu link provavelmente vai dar erro 403 para você e para todo mundo que não seja eu. O que acho que acontece é que o dropbox gera um link para a imagem real exclusivo para um único visualizador (provavelmente por razões de segurança). Desta forma, este link é inútil para a engine da StackExchange, pois causará um erro 403 qando a engine do StackExchange tentar carregá-lo. Por outro lado o link simplificado que é o que você compartilha, não se trata exatamente de uma imagem e sim de uma página de internet, e por tal motivo ele não pode ser carregado como imagem.

As duas únicas coisas que acho que a StackExchange poderia fazer é:

- Implementar um tratamento especial para o caso de links de imagens do dropbox. Entretanto, provavelmente dirão que a prioridade e o ganho referente a isso é baixo demais, além de ser algo que pode ser contornado facilmente pelos usuários. Para piorar, a implementação poderia quebrar de forma súbita, espontânea e sem aviso prévio se o dropbox alterasse a sua implementação por qualquer motivo.
- Fazer um acordo com a dropbox para resolver este problema. Isso é algo que não depende apenas de alterar o código, e sim de negociações entre empresas por um ganho provavelmente baixo demais para valer a pena.

De qualquer forma, o melhor lugar para perguntar ou propor isso seria [no metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), que é o site da StackExchange para debates e discussões sobre a rede StackExchange.